# cannot read property 'neighbours' of undefined

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

http://jsfiddle.net/eM6jU/200/

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'neighbours' of undefined.

it is emanating from the following loop, any idea why is this happening?
cola.js line 3332

```
**Watch Expressions**

    "i ": Object
    length: 144
    source: "ds"
    target: "sdf"



 while (i--) {   var e = this.es[i];
    var u = getSourceIndex(e), v = getTargetIndex(e);
    var d = getLength(e);
    this.neighbours[u].neighbours.push(new Neighbour(v, d));
    this.neighbours[v].neighbours.push(new Neighbour(u, d));`

            }
```

Comment: Could you provide a complete example please?

Comment: trying to do a graph which can look like http://marvl.infotech.monash.edu/webcola/examples/ariel.html

Comment: Hmm, looks like a bug in cola.js.

Comment: should i raise an issue to them?

Comment: Yes, I would do that.

Comment: i raised it https://github.com/tgdwyer/WebCola/issues/128

Answer (score 0):

The solution is found in [this issue](https://github.com/tgdwyer/WebCola/issues/128) submitted by OP.

Basically, `cola.js` expects the links to be a certain format, namely the source and target attributes need to be indexes into the node array (not the names of the nodes). Here is an example of some properly formatted data:

```
{
    "nodes": ["Node A", "Node B", "Node C"],
    "links": {
        {"source": 0, "target": 1},
        {"source": 1, "target": 2},
        {"source": 2, "target": 0}
    }
}
```